# Derivative of $x\dot x$

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I found that the derivative of $\mathbf {x \dot x}$ is $\mathbf {x\ddot x + \dot x^2}$. I understand the first part of the result is due to the product rule, but what about the square power in the other part? It should be the product rule AND the chain rule, but how are they applied in this case exactly?

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, Aero. It shows utter disrespect to those who have tried to help you by posting answers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how to perform a rollback?

Comment: @insi, you click where it says "edited x hours ago" (or something similar), that will show you all the versions the question has gone through, you pick out one you like, and you click on "rollback" next to that version. You may need to have some number of points for that feature to be enabled for you.

Comment: Thanks that’s figured out @GerryMyerson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product rule is

$$(uv)^{\prime} = u^{\prime}v + v^{\prime}u$$

We have

$$u = x, \; v = \dot x \implies u^{\prime} = \dot x, \; v^{\prime} = \ddot x$$

Therefore,

$$(x\dot x)^{\prime} = \dot x\dot x + \ddot xx = \boxed{x\ddot x + {\dot x} ^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

By the product rule:
$$\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t}(uv) = \dot u v + u\dot v.$$

In this case: $u= x$, $v = \dot x$ and
$$\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t}(x \dot x) = \dot x \dot x + x\ddot x = x\ddot x + \dot x ^2.$$

Comment: We are differentiating w.r.t. $x$, not $t$, right?

Comment: No, $x$ is the function and $\dot x$ is its derivative with respect to an unnamed variable (for example, we can call it $t$).

Answer (score 1):

The product rule is the following: $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$. So $(xx')'= x'x' + xx'' = (x')^2 + xx''$

You don't need the chain rule, I guess.